# Making a blackjack program using javascript, cant splice top card (obj) of a deck (obJ) into hand

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I create a deck object and put card objects into it and shuffle it, now I am trying to somehow splice out the first card object in deck into either the player.hand or dealer.hand, how do I go about this?

(this does not work)

```
player.hand = deck.splice(0);
```

> TypeError: deck.splice is not a function

Sorry for the noob question

```
var cardname = ["Ace", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "sevem", "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king"]
var suit = ["spades", "hearts", "clubs", "diamonds"]
var value = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
var deck = {};
var player = {
  hand: null
}
var dealer = {
  hand: null 
}

function card(cardname, suit, value) {
  this.cardname = cardname;
  this.suit = suit;
  this.value = value;
}

function createdeck(){

    cardindeck = 0;
for(i=0;  i<cardname.length;  i++){
    for(k=0;  k<suit.length;  k++){
        deck[cardindeck] = new card(cardname[i], suit[k], value[i]);
        cardindeck++;
}
}
}

function shuffledeck(deck) {
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  var temp = null;


  for (i=Object.keys(deck).length-1; i>0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Object.keys(deck).length));
    temp = deck[i];
    deck[i] = deck[j];
    deck[j] = temp;
  }
}


function dealplayer(deck, player) {
player.hand = deck.splice(0);
}

function dealdealer(deck, dealer) {
 player.hand = deck.splice(0);
 }
}
```

Comment: Why are you duplicating your question?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an array instead of an object.

```
var deck = [];
//         ^^
```

Then you could use native [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) with two parameters for geting one item.

```
selectedCard = deck.splice(0, 1)[0];
//                            ^ ^^^
//                     count /   \\\ get the first element of the spliced array
```

And in `createdeck`, you could omit the index counter and use [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
function createdeck() {
    var i, k;
    for (i = 0;  i < cardname.length; i++) {
        for (k = 0; k < suit.length; k++) {
            deck.push(new card(cardname[i], suit[k], value[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

In `shuffledeck` replace

```
Object.keys(deck).length
```

with the length property of an array

```
deck.length
```

Complete code with some minor changes:

```js
function Card(cardname, suit, value) {
    this.cardname = cardname;
    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
}

function createDeck(deck) {
    var i, k;
    deck.length = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < cardname.length; i++) {
        for (k = 0; k < suit.length; k++) {
            deck.push(new Card(cardname[i], suit[k], value[i]));
        }
    }
}

function shuffleDeck(deck) {
    var i = deck.length,
        j,
        temp,
        length = deck.length;

    while (i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
        temp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[j];
        deck[j] = temp;
    }
}

function dealPlayer(deck, player) {
    player.hand.push(deck.splice(0, 1)[0]);
}

function dealDealer(deck, dealer) {
    dealer.hand.push(deck.splice(0, 1)[0]);
}

var cardname = ["Ace", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king"],
    suit = ["spades", "hearts", "clubs", "diamonds"],
    value = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10],
    deck = [],
    player = { hand: [] },
    dealer = { hand: [] };

createDeck(deck);
console.log('deck', deck);
shuffleDeck(deck);
console.log('deck', deck);
dealPlayer(deck, player)
console.log('player', player);
dealDealer(deck, dealer);
console.log('dealer', dealer);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I made all the changes you suggest and now the createdeck function doesnt work anymore,

Comment: createdeck();
^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier